# Procedural texture is not visible in render

Tags: rendering, texturing, procedural

I made procedural texture, but it is only visible in material viewport shading but not in rendered view or rendered image.

Can anyone please advise me what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Could you possibly post the .blend file?

Comment: Your node tree is an incoherent mess. You have textures connected to shader input, and shader output driving colors, no input for texture coordinates. Mind your data flow and match socket colors

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Texture coordinate input might not be necessary depending on what OP is after. Regarding the nodes - yes. Posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the 'Add Shader' node before the color ramp node. This is because the 'fac' input to the color ramp node should be a value. Instead the 'Add Shader' node gives a shader which the colorramp node can't understand properly.Also, ideally the 'Add Shader' node should take shaders as inputs instead of color or values.
[image]

In the place of the 'Add Shader' node, use 'Math' node and change it to add.Math node can be accessed by Converter>Math

[image]

The node setup will look something like this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using an Add Shader, but aren't inputting any shaders there but only values from your textures. Replace that Add Shader by a Color - Mix RGB node and switch that to Add. Then it should work as expected.